# What can cause cutting of the slash in the url?

Tags: http, url, https

Let's say I have url similar to this:

```
https://sprerererer.blablabla.systems/confirm-reservation/5cbe0e49e611ac1f06b39342a9b35c93a69cef6f8fbe6136752af4c8fe86eb64323031382d31312d31392031313a30303a3434
```

(due to security reasons, it's not my real url)

If I paste it to chrome it redirects me to:

```
https://sprerererer.blablabla.systemsconfirm-reservation/5cbe0e49e611ac1f06b39342a9b35c93a69cef6f8fbe6136752af4c8fe86eb64323031382d31312d31392031313a30303a3434
```

cutting of the slash at the end of domain. I never encountered anything like it. What can cause it? Is it chrome? Is it my server's fault?

Comment: Most likely the cause is some redirection rule implemented on the server side. Either on the level of the http server or inside the applicatiohn logic you use.

Comment: And by the way: there is absolutely no reason to obfuscate your URLs. That does _not_ offer additional security, it typically only indicates an undefined fear that the own solution is everything but robust. Think of it this way: if you publish something on the internet (which you apparently do), then what you publish is available. So it needs to have a level of quality that you trust in so that you dare to publish it. Or the effects of a lower quality is so trivial that you dare it anyway. If the only measure for quality you take is to "keep your URLs secret" then you have a very deep problem.

Comment: @arkascha - I strongly disagree, I am almost sure that if I asked about security problem on a production website and I have and posted my real url here, somebody would try to break it. My problem is not very vulnerable I think, but I still don't see any reason why should I post my real website url.

Comment: Certainly my remark also applies to production systems. Your solution needs to be that rubost that you can grant everyone to _try_ to break it. Everything else means that you are afraid of reality. Keeping a URL secret won't work, that is naive. Obfuscation does _not_ offer security, it only makes things more complex and _less_ secure in the end, since if offers a _false_ sense of security.

Comment: sure, I get your point, but right now I KNOW that my system is vulnerable and by asking questions here I'm trying to make it more secure. I wouldn't ask questions here if I would be sure of quality of my product as of this moment. And I think your post applies more to finished and tested products, not work in progress.

Comment: Back to my initial comment: I pointed to redirection rules. Did you check those?

Comment: oh, yes, that is definitely the problem. Thank you.